# Braintree Webhooks: How can I notify customer that their subscription has been canceled

Tags: braintree

When I receive the subscription canceled webhook I can't retrieve the customers information via their payment info because it is deleted.  Specifically I am trying to get the customers e-mail.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree.</sub>

You can extract the customer id from the webhook. You didn't specify your client library language, but this is how you would do it in Ruby:

```
webhook_notification = Braintree::WebhookNotification.parse(
  bt_signature_param, bt_payload_param
)

customer_id = webhook_notification.subject.subscription.transactions.first.customer.id
```

Pass the customer id from your webhook into a Customer.find call. Then inspect the result object to extract the email address.

[More information on parsing webhooks here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/parse/).

If you have any additional questions, feel free to reach out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).

Comment: Unless it's a rubyism I think the `.subject` there is spurious.  (I'll find out for sure later tonight when my test subscriptions come through :) )